# After building AWS Amplify "Error: Invariant failed"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

My project works in local without any problems. However, after building with AWS Amplify, an error such as the screenshot below occurs when problems occur when routing to other pages. (example "/" to "/page")

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg5Pr.png)

I don't know how to solve the above error because there is no problem in local.

```
    "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@ethersproject/providers": "^5.5.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.4.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.8",
    "@web3-react/core": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/injected-connector": "^6.0.7",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.0.2",
    "caver-js": "^1.6.8",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^6.0.0-0",
    "react-player": "^2.10.1",
    "react-random-reveal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-select": "^5.2.2",
    "react-timer-hook": "^3.0.5",
    "recoil": "^0.7.3-alpha.2",
    "recoil-persist": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "styled-reset": "^4.4.0",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "swiper": "^8.1.5",
    "usehooks-ts": "^2.4.0",
    "vercel": "^24.2.3",
    "web3": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aos": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.4",
    "@types/react-responsive": "^8.0.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/recoil": "^0.0.9",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "@types/styled-system": "^5.1.15",
    "@types/swiper": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  }
```

Comment: It would probably be more helpful to share the code that gets you from `"/"` to `"/page"` as it is rather difficult to help diagnose or debug code we can't see. Please try to edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.